# Store the method return or call it repeatedly?

Tags: c#, optimization

If I am going to access a function for a value multiple time for example myString.SubString(5,5) I am presented with two options.

1. I do just that, call it (let's say) three times.
2. I store is as string tempString = myString.SubString(5,5) and use tempString three times.

Say this is part of a function I end up calling a million times in one frame, in case 1 I am using up more cpu than case 2 yes?

In case 2 however I am creating a local variable millions of times and using up more memory until garbage is collected maybe next frame.

I'm using a very small example, but in general practice if one is better than the other, I can certainly foresee times when making the proper choice could affect performance.

Is it a case by case choice to use more memory or more CPU, is one practice generally better than the other?

Comment: When I use a piece of data more than 1 time, I usually store it. Since you don't want for your program to run multiple time the same piece of code to return data you should already have.

Comment: I always opt for case 2.. if you're going to need the exact same results more than once.. why rework it out.. yes you may call it a million times and yes, a million times 1 variable gets made, used and forgotten, its better than 3 million calls to play with strings.

Comment: Quite hard to imagine the case. It is better if you have a code to put. But usually the condition to decide whether we will/will not use temp variable is if the original variable is still needed, then we keep it. If not, just use the original variable

Comment: Agreed, if the return value doesn't change I'd always assign that value to a Property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the difference about object allocation and local variables.

First let's deal with the basics. If you call `string.SubString` and it returns *less than the original string*, then it will create a new string object. Every time. I would expect it to return the original string if you give it indexes and such so that the entire string is returned but that's irrelevant here.

So this will create a new object, *every time*:

```
myString.SubString(5,5)
```

Now, if you store this new object into a local variable, the *only thing* you do is start controlling the *lifetime* of that object. It may or may not actually have an impact on when the garbage collector can collect this new string object, but this does in no way create extra objects, you're *only* storing the already created object *reference* into a local variable.

Yes, the local variable takes space, however if you use the result of that `Substring` call inside an expression then something similar to a local variable will be created anyway, it's just the compiler that does it for you behind the scenes.

So if you're doing something in a loop, and each loop iteration will require this substring 3 times, then *yes*, definitely store it in a variable to avoid the 2 extra object allocations and the cost associated with the 2 extra calls to `Substring`.

Comment: Because it's local, that makes sense, it either exists or it exists. I was storing things generally just because it felt better, I wasn't positive of the "correct" explanation though. Now I am! Thank you.\